# Unable to render data into grid column using JSON results

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs6

I have a grid store with something like this.

```
var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        actionMethods : {
            read : 'POST'
        },
        url : 'getECIAgentWrapperJobs.do',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty : 'rows',
            totalProperty : 'results'
        }
    },
    pageSize : 3,
    autoLoad : {start: 0, limit: 3}
});
```

Clearly it makes an AJAX request to the url.
The JSON response that I am getting for this store looks something like this :

```
{  
   "results":2,
   "rows":[  
      {  
         "pkTable1":1,
         "name":"Rick",
         "eciAgentJob":{  
            "pkTable2":11,
            "name":"Play Local Ar",
         },
      }
   ],
   "msg":null,
   "success":true,
}
```

Now this is how my grid looks :

```
var mappedEciAgentJobsGrids = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
        store : gridStore,
        columns : [
            {
                dataIndex : 'pkTable1',
                header : 'Pk of table 1'
            },
            {
                dataIndex : 'name',
                header : 'Name'
            },
            {
                dataIndex : 'eciAgentJob.pkTable2',
                header : 'Pk of Table 2'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Now in my UI the first 2 columns(with dataIndex: pkTable2 and name respectively) load fine. But for the 3rd one it does not.
I know it is because I have used dataIndex as 'eciAgentJob.pkTable2'. But then what is that way to load data in columns when we get response like the way I got(where eciAgentJob is a object inside the original JSON).
Please help.

Edit : I dont want to use a renderer due to some other use case reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Define a new field in your model and map with the required field. In convert function pick any value from the record.

```
 Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string ' },
        {
         name: 'columnName',

         convert: function (value, record) {
             return "return what ever you want"
         }
     }

    ]
});
```

Comment: could you please help with some more code(mainly for store and grid). Actually I am completely new to extjs. Thanks anyways

Comment: Exactly as you did but I would indeed add a model to the store. This answer shows an example definition. I would use mapping: 'eciAgentJob.pkTable2' but the convert works too... Just add model: 'User' in the store config like this answer suggested..https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html

Comment: sure I will help. I prepare a fiddle for you. Please use as a reference. I created a new column with name NamePhone in the model and storing name+phone
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2tb8&view/editor

if you want to access the next node in json then use record.getData().node.node insted of record.get('name')